# I am working on a project where you have to input a matrix that has an arbitrary size. I am using python. Suggestions?

Tags: python, matrix

Entering arbitrary sized matrices to manipulate them using different operations.

Comment: So what is your question, exactly?

Comment: Hi Nathan, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you share some of the ideas you've had yourself, so we have something to bounce our ideas off of?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Comment: take a look at `numpy` `array` and `matrix`

Comment: I am somewhat proficient in C++ and I'm learning Python right now and I'm trying to learn python. I was thinking of creating a vector where the user gives the input and then the program runs certain algorithms on it to identify the characteristics of the matrix. I'm working on the pseudo code part for that and I want to be able to enter the first matrix with an arbitrary size.

Answer (score 1):

Read the input till Ctrl+d, split by newline symbols  first and then split the results by spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Think about who is using this programme, and how, then develop an interface which meets those needs.